# Showing picture from other site displays weird picture instead

Tags: html, caching, image

I am making a Facebook-app were you can browse you and your friend's likes on a webpage that displays lots of funny pictures. The problem is that when I link to these pictures, they appear as something completly else. Like a placeholder or something. It displays correctly if it's cached (I think).

Take a look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jVBSk/ . If you rightclick at the image, you get an other filename than the one in the source.

How can I avoid this, making the page display the correct images?

Comment: Does this display the correct image? http://windowsnaarlinux.nl/test.php Just an experiment. I can see it's displaying another image than the one displayed on Jsfiddle, but I don't know if this is the one it's supposed to show.

Comment: Yes it does. Mind posting the script at pastebin or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to have some kind of hot-linking protection on it. This one's not very well made, so it's quite easy to bypass.

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents($_GET['image']);
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
$image = imagecreatefromstring($file);
imagejpeg($image);
imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

Then call the script like this: `script.php?image=http%3A%2F%2Fgif.artige.no%2Fstore%2F10%2F10002.jpg` 
The image URL has to be encoded. This can be done using `urlencode()` in PHP, or here's an online tool to do it: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

So in HTML that'd be something like this: `<img src="script.php?image=http%3A%2F%2Fgif.artige.no%2Fstore%2F10%2F10002.jpg" alt="[Image]" />`

Comment: I was trying to avoid this, but it looks like a simple solution. Thank you so much for the code, I'll wrap it up with ajax to avoid webpages to timeout.

Comment: Just like to inform that I ended up using a similar curl-function for this. Works as expected.

Answer (score -1):

The website is checking the referrer to see if it's their domain, or not.  If it's not, it's returning this "do not steal this" image.  (If anyone can translate that, I'm sure that's what it's saying).

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referrer_spoofing.

Comment: It says Artige.no loves you very much in norwegian :P IS there any way to avoid this? I am not stealing the images, I just want to link to them, instead of having to download each and every one of them to my local server.

Comment: EDIT: DO I have to load the images using curl, modify the headers and then place the content on the page? There's no way to simply use the img-tag?

Answer (score -1):

What you do is called [hot-linking](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hotlink) and is frowned-upon by many website owners..

The problem is that you are stealing their bandwidth, and as a solution they provide a different image instead of the requested one when the requesting page is not from their own domain..